# docker-machine to connect with external host

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-machine

I'm using docker-machine v0.2 and I have two host(hostA, hostB) with OS Ubuntu 14.04. Then I was follow the [official doc](https://docs.docker.com/machine/) to install and use docker-machine.Finally After initial steps I have installed on my hostA: docker and docker-machine.

When I use example of driver virtualbox(`docker-machine create --driver virtualbox dev`) all it's fine. I have one virtual machine with boot2docker named "dev" as follow:

```
docker-machine ls
NAME   ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM
dev             virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.101:2376
```

Then I try to provision docker on hostB but I can't found the right way to do it. Anyone know how do it? It's possible use docker-machine to provision external host without cloud provider driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must upgrade docker-machine to version docker-machine 0.3.0 which include generic driver.

Then you may use like this:

```
docker-machine create --driver generic --generic-ip-address some-ip --generic-ssh-user some-user dev
```

there are more parameters present in [docker-machine documentation](https://github.com/docker/machine/blob/master/docs/index.md#generic)

Comment: ok, your notes work fine on next version of XXXX. But version 0.3.0 it's not released yet, also I can upgrade to v0.3.0-RC-1.